# integer arguments for c++

Tags: c++, arguments

I have a sort of calculator in C++ that should accept arguments when executed. However, when I enter 7 as an argument, it might come out to be 10354 when put into a variable. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, int argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    int a;
    int b;
    if(argc==3){
        a=argv[1];
        b=argv[2];
    }
    else{
        cout << "Please enter a number:";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Please enter another number:";
        cin >> b;
    }
    cout << "Addition:" << a+b << endl;
    cout << "Subtaction:" << a-b << endl;
    cout << "Multiplycation:" << a*b << endl;
    cout << "Division:" << static_cast<long double>(a)/b << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always compile your code with maximum warnings enabled.  `-Wall` when using gcc.  I suspect the compiler would have stopped you from making this mistake with a warning about converting a pointer to an integer.

Comment: @deft_code? Where the conversion from pointer to integer?  `main` simply has the wrong type signature.

Comment: FYI, most mathematicians require checking the denominator for zero before division.  I heard it was illegal.  I believe the programming term is "Undefined behavior".  The program will generate a signal or exception.  Worlds may fall apart.  Who knows?

Comment: @Thomas: Depending of the floating-point exception mode, the program may just print `1#IND` or the like.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wherever did you get `int argv[]`?  The second argument to `main` is `char* argv[]`.

You can convert these command line arguments from string to integer using `strtol` or to floating-point using `strtod`.

For example:

```
    a=strtol(argv[1], nullptr, 0);
    b=strtol(argv[2], nullptr, 0);
```

But you can't just change the parameter type, because the operating system is going to give you your command-line arguments in string form whether you like it or not.

NOTE: You must `#include <stdlib.h>` (or `#include <cstdlib>` and `using std::strtol;`) to use the `strtol` function.

---

If you want error-checking, use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.  Using it is almost as easy, and it also gives you a pointer to the location in the string where parsing terminated.  If that points to the terminating NUL, parsing was successful.  And of course it is good that you verify `argc` to make sure the user provided enough parameters, and avoid trying to read missing parameters from `argv`.

Example of error checking:

```
char* endp;
a = strtol(argv[1], &endp, 0);
if (endp == argv[1] || *endp) { /* failed, handle error */ }
```

Comment: Another method for converting from string to integer is to use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @Thomas: If you need to handle thousands separators and currency symbols and stuff, yes.  Otherwise it's just 5 times as much code and 20 times slower.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the arguments, but not the function atoi().

Answer (score 4):

The function signature is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. argv is an array of string pointers.

If the argument is 7, it will be in the form of a string ("7"). Use `atoi()` to convert it to the number 7.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that function. When I used static_cast and the arguments int argc, and char *argv[], it would result in an error.

Comment: @Rob: If you were casting char * to int, be glad your compiler wouldn't allow it. If you could compile it, you'd have a program with a serious bug. A string is an array of characters. The value of character '7' is not 7. If you want to perform math with 7, you have to convert the string.

Answer (score 2):

Second argument in the main should either either be `char* argv[]` or `char** argv`. Then you have to have convert them to `int`.